# Expo Router "Link": Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to use the expo router to build my navigation menu, and placed this code on the drawer example:

```
    const navigationView = () => (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.navigationContainer]}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Close drawer"
          onPress={() => drawer.current.closeDrawer()}
        />
        <Link href="/screens/HomeScreen" style={styles.navigationLink}>Home</Link>
      </View>
    );
```

However, after building the app, and trying to click the link, I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined
```

I'm not running in TypeScript, rather just using pure javascript. What could possibly be going wrong with this?

Comment: Have you any updates on progress? Someone else (in a now deleted answer) is interested in a solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I found out there were still a couple of configurations missing in babel.config.js, app.json and then the folder structure I had to follow in the app folder.

I made an example available [here](https://github.com/rodhoff/expo-router-drawer-example).

I have built the example based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOYl5PdFC6U&t=693s) video.

I hope it helps whoever needs to work with that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the solution for me was to implement `NavigationContainer`, please check the next link:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/

In my case was:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={ArticleNavigator} />
    <Tab.Screen name="About" component={AboutMe} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```